# How to shade the area bounded by more than 2 functions?

Tags: filling

I am trying to shade the area bounded by the lines $y=2$, $y=-x+2$ and the parabola $y=x^2$. The plot is shown below. The area I'm talking about is the that bounded by the 4 black points. I am trying to shade it and I don't know how. Your assitance is appreciated.

```
Plot[{2 - x, x^2, 2}, {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {-1, 5}, 
     PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thick}, {Dashed}, {Blue, Thick}},  
     Epilog -> {Black, PointSize[0.025], Point[pts]}]
```

[image]

Comment: `Show[
 RegionPlot[y < 2 && y < 2 - x && y > x^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1, 3}],
 Plot[{2 - x, x^2, 2}, {x, -3, 3}]]`

Comment: @Kuba `Show[RegionPlot[Min[2, 2 - x] > y > x^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1, 3}],  Plot[{2 - x, x^2, 2}, {x, -3, 3}]]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
pts = {{-Sqrt@2, 2}, {1, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 0}};
opts = {PlotRange -> {-1, 5}, PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thick}, {Dashed}, {Blue, Thick}}, 
        Epilog -> {Black, PointSize[0.025], Point[pts]}, 
        Filling -> {3 -> {{2}, {Transparent, Lighter@Lighter@Blue}}}};
Show[
 Plot[{2 - x, x^2, 2}, {x, -3, 0}, Evaluate@opts],
 Plot[{2, x^2, 2 - x}, {x, 0, 3}, Evaluate@opts], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 7):

```
Plot[{2 - x, x^2, 2}, {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {-1, 5}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thick}, {Dashed}, {Blue, Thick}},
 Prolog -> 
  First@Show@
    BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
     ImplicitRegion[y <= 2 - x && y <= 2 && y >= x^2, {x, y}]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Someday

```
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
 ImplicitRegion[y <= 2 - x && y <= 2 && y >= x^2, {x, y}]]["GraphicsComplex"]
```

will work reliably.

Comment: "some day" I'll have v10. +1 :)

Answer (score 5):

```
Plot[{ConditionalExpression[x^2, x^2 <= Min[2, 2 - x]], Min[2, 2 - x],2 - x, 2, x^2}, {x, -3, 3}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, FillingStyle -> Yellow, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[{Opacity[1], Yellow}], Opacity[0], 
   Directive[{Opacity[1], Red}], Green, Directive[{Dashed, Orange}]}, BaseStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

Use `MeshFunctions` and `Mesh` to add the intersection points

```
Plot[{ConditionalExpression[x^2, x^2 <= Min[2, 2 - x]], Min[2, 2 - x],
   2 - x, 2, x^2}, {x, -3, 3},
 Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, FillingStyle -> Yellow, 
 Mesh -> {{0}, {0}}, MeshStyle -> PointSize[.03],
 MeshFunctions -> {# &, ConditionalExpression[Min[2, 2 - #] - #^2, #2 + # <= 2 && #2 <= 2] &}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[{Opacity[1], Yellow}], Opacity[0], 
   Directive[{Opacity[1], Red}], Green, Directive[{Dashed, Orange}]}, 
 BaseStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot[{ConditionalExpression[{x, v x^2 + (1-v) Min[2, 2 - x]}, x^2 <= Min[2, 2 - x]], 
 {x, 2 - x}, {x, 2}, {x, x^2}}, {x, -3, 3}, {v, 0, 1}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, PlotStyle -> ColorData[1, "ColorList"], 
 BaseStyle -> Thick, Frame -> False, Axes -> True, Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps if you put the `ConditionalExpression` first its boundaries will be overwritten by the other plots, instead of the other way around.

Comment: Thank you @Michael, very good point.

Answer (score 1):

```
pts = {{-Sqrt@2, 2}, {1, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 0}};
prolog = Plot[{x^2, Piecewise[{{2 - x, x > 0}, {2, x < 0}}]}, 
    {x, -Sqrt@2, 1}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}][[1]];
```

I have applied `prolog` with `Piecewise`

```
Plot[{2 - x, x^2, 2}, {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {-1, 5}, 
    PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thick}, {Dashed}, {Blue, Thick}},
    Prolog -> prolog, 
    Epilog -> {Black, PointSize[0.025], Point[pts]}
]
```

> [image: Blockquote]